# How I can use iMacros to edit an page's html?

Tags: html, automation, edit, imacros

Using iMacros, I need to change this html command

`<td class="dr-dscr-inact rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '5'});">5</td>`

to

`<td class="dr-dscr-inact rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'n'});">5</td>`

where "n" is any number. I don't know how to use iMacros for it, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
SET n 11
URL GOTO=javascript:var<SP>eltTdPage5=document.querySelector("td[class*='dr-dscr-inact<SP>rich-datascr-inact'][onclick*=\"{'page':<SP>'5'}\"]");eltTdPage5.outerHTML=eltTdPage5.outerHTML.replace(/5/g,{{n}});undefined;
```

Comment: It didn't worked :/
Would you like I post here the iMacros' commands to send you to the site? This way you can understand my point better.

Comment: Why not?.. If this issue is still actual for you.